# Declaring variable type as varchar with default value

Tags: mysql

I am writing a stored procedure and i this is the code i am using

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER le_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON inbox
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
declare last_inserted_number VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '0800100200' NOT NULL;
declare last_inserted_message VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'Lorem Ipsum' NOT NULL;

set last_inserted_number = NEW.in_number;
set last_inserted_message = NEW.in_message;

insert into transactions (message,tel) values(last_inserted_message,last_inserted_number);
END$$
delimiter ;
```

When i execute this i get this error

> /* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'NOT NULL DEFAULT '0800100200'; declare
>   last_inserted_message VARCHAR(100) NOT N' at line 5 */ /* Affected
>   rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 0 of 1 query: 0.000
>   sec. */

The problem seems to be at the point i am declaring this variables

```
declare last_inserted_number VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '0800100200' NOT NULL;
    declare last_inserted_message VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'Lorem Ipsum' NOT NULL;
```

Why is the error appearing while the varchar has the default value set well?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stored procedure variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-variables.html) can't be declared as NOT NULL.

Remove "NOT NULL".